# How to extract only one file from a zip file on the mac command line?

Tags: macos, command-line, unzip

I have a zip file with the following contents:

```
myzipfile.zip
  mydir1
    myfile1.txt
    myfile2.txt
  mydir2
    myfile3.txt
    myfile4.txt
```

I want to write a mac command line to only extract `mydir2` - something like

```
unzip myzipfile.zip -magicparameter mydir2
```

My question is: **How to extract only one file from a zip file on the mac command line?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unzip zip_file.zip path/to/file.txt`

This will extract the specified file.